# Why does an entity need an inverse?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, entity-relationship

I have a very simple Core data Model comprising of a single Gallery which contains multiple Images. It seems to me that it should be enough for a Gallery to have a one-to-many relationship with Image, but if I don't also establish an inverse relationship from Image back to gallery I get Compiler warnings and errors. From an object-oriented perspective it seems to me that an Image shouldn't know or care if it is in a Gallery or any other ManagedObject so why does the compiler force me to create this inverse relationship? Having a 'gallery' property on the image seems very wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Core Data uses the inverse relationship to help maintain referential integrity.  When you change a relationship or delete an object it speeds up performance dramatically.  Without the inverse those same actions would potentially result in full table scans.

In my opinion, not having an inverse should be an error instead of a warning.  The difference can be dramatic in some fairly common situations.

Just imagine a multi-entity cascade delete without them.  Could take long enough that the OS thinks your app has crashed.

Comment: That's what they always say. "Referential integrity." That does not make sense to me. If an entity has an inverse, then I can see how it needs to be declared. But if as in the OP's case, an image has no reference to a gallery, nothing on the image needs to be changed if the gallery is deleted, or if the image is removed from the gallery, etc.

Comment: I think you're right, it has more to do with performance. If that's the case, why can't Core Data just come up with an automatic behind-the-scenes inverse? Or is there some situation where it's not possible to automatically deduce what the inverse should be?

Comment: Thanks. I can't pretend to understand your answer as I don't have a good knowledge of this domain, but if it is significantly more performant I suppose that is a good enough reason. However utterly breaking encapsulation seems like an appalling price to pay. In an object graph consisting of User:Galleries:Gallery:Image, Image can get a reference to User which is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't apply oo principles to database structures - they aren't in  the same domain.  Core Data is about tables and rows and pointers between them.  Let's look at referential integrity and your gallery example.  If you don't have a relationship from an image to a gallery, when you go to delete an image, the system will not know to remove its reference in the gallery. You could argue with some validity that this sort of detail should be taken care of, but I think you that's the way it is, and you should just live with it.  Maybe send a bug report to Apple..

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is that Managed Objects are Objects, but they are still bound by the rules of Database Structures. I shouldn't have to care about an inverse reference. This is detail that should be handled behind the scenes.