# Core Data Object fetching with Predicates

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a model like this
Product ---> Options (One-to-many relationship, no -invers)

Option -------> Size (one - to - one relationship, no-invers)

Option -------> sold_out (attribute,BOOLEAN)

Now I want to fetch an array of all sizes of all options of all products where option.sold_out is NO.

How can I use Predicates to fetch it from Core Data rather than iterating through arrays of products an options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **NEVER use one-way relationships** in Core Data. You may not use it by yourself, but Core Data need it for referential integrity.

[Why does an entity need an inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779464/why-does-an-entity-need-an-inverse)

Now,about your request. You could use something like this.

```
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
request.prdicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY option.sold_out == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
```

## UPDATE

Now,it's you, who need the inverse — because there is no adequate way for you to do this request without **Size---->Option** relationship. If you had one, let's call it **option**,you could do your request like this:

```
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Size" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
request.prdicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"option.sold_out == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will give me an array of Products and I need an array of sizes. A size is in Option. Can we do that any how

Comment: Thanks, I think I made mistake by not keeping up the inverses.